# How to upload JSON to AWS CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

It seems like I am missing some pretty simple things, but I can't figure out what's a problem here.
I want to upload the JSON file which is next:

```
[{
    "name": "Mark"
}]
```

After creating an Index field `name`:
[image]

Then I pick `Upload Documents` on a Dashboard page:
[image]

And then I have an error:

```
Your upload includes 1 document containing the following fields: content content_encoding content_type resourcename
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Also make sure there are no `null` values in your JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am currently trying to use it and I have the same problem.

Try this :

**1/ Create a JSON batch to add your data to your search domain**

For example :

```
[
  {
    "type": "add",
    "id": "uniqueid:1",
    "fields": {
        "name": "jack",
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "add",
    "id": "uniqueid:2",
    "fields": {
        "name": "pierre",
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "add",
    "id": "uniqueid:3",
    "fields": {
        "name": "bob",
    }
  }
]
```

**2/ Now go to your domains dashboard and click "upload document" : upload this JSON batch**

**3/ Go to "run a test search" and try to find "bob" for example : you should have your bob data !**

The documentation about the batch : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/preparing-data.html

To upload data to your search domain you need to respect this batch format, look the documentation and the guidelines :)

You can do it too using a bucket that will be use to trigger a lambda function, the idea is : when you will upload a file in the bucket, launch your lambda function to read this file and create a batch file that will add the new data to your index. And when you remove a file : you delete the data to your index !

Look this tutorial if you need some help with the lambda function : https://medium.com/devopslinks/build-your-own-document-search-engine-using-amazon-web-services-82d5b165d96c

Hope it helps !

Answer (score -1):

```
[
  {
    'type': 'add',
    'id': 'item1',
    'fields': {
        'name': 'salt',
    }
  },
  {
    'type': 'add',
    'id': 'item2',
    'fields': {
        'name': 'sugar',
    }
  },
  {
    'type': 'add',
    'id': 'item3',
    'fields': {
        'name': 'rice',
    }
  }
]
```

I tried to upload the above data, but I was getting error. So, I modified single quote ' to double quote ", and it worked out. I was able to upload to aws cloudsearch.

```
[
  {
    "type": "add",
    "id": "item1",
    "fields": {
        "name": "salt",
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "add",
    "id": "item2",
    "fields": {
        "name": "sugar",
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "add",
    "id": "item3",
    "fields": {
        "name": "rice",
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This should be just a comment. Furthermore, the example is not helping because it is not related to the question.